# Understanding multiple inheritance of python

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code snippet

```
class Test(object):
    def check(self, x):
        x = x + 10
        return x

class Test1(object):
    def check(self, x):
        x = super().check(x)
        x = x + 2
        return x

class Test2(Test1, Test):
    pass


a = Test2()
print (a.check(2))
```

when I run the code it outputs 14

My question is Since Test1 does not have any parent when i use super() method why does it call the check method of Test class?

since it calls the check method of Test x will 12 and then check method of Test1 will make it 14

So i am trying to understand what is going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve the method `check(x)`, python uses Method Resolution Ordering (MRO) for the sake of complete inheritance hierarchy. That means Python traverses the hierarchy tree from left to right in depth-first manner.

Calling `x = super().check(x)` by `Test2`, Python finds the method of the second base class `Test` and calls that function.

Note that order of inheritance for the child class is crucial.
For example introducing a third test class, which `Test2` will be child of

```
class Test3(object):
def check(self, x):
    x = x + 38
    return x
```

E.g. `Test2` will inherit in this particular order `Test2(Test1, Test, Test3)`, the result will be still 14, but if `Test2(Test1, Test3, Test1)` looks like this, the answer will be 42.

Further reading to [MRO.](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html)